# Poor wireless quality with a Realtek RLT8187

Tags: wireless, 12.10, realtek

I'm using a Toshiba Satelite L300D laptop that came preinstalled with Windows Vista but since i changed to Ubuntu I haven't been able to have a good Wi-Fi signal even with 2-3 bars. I'm new to using Ubuntu and was hoping that there may be a resolution to this problem.

My Ethernet/ Wi-Fi Drivers are:

> > > > *-network
> > > >                description: Ethernet interface
> > > >                product: RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
> > > >                vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
> > > >                physical id: 0
> > > >                bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
> > > >                logical name: eth0
> > > >                version: 02
> > > >                serial: 00:1e:33:4c:8b:6f
> > > >                size: 10Mbit/s
> > > >                capacity: 100Mbit/s
> > > >                width: 64 bits
> > > >                clock: 33MHz
> > > >                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
> > > >                configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
> > > >                resources: irq:44 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:f1010000-f1010fff memory:f1000000-f100ffff
> > > >           *-network
> > > >                description: Wireless interface
> > > >                physical id: 1
> > > >                bus info: usb@1:6
> > > >                logical name: wlan0
> > > >                serial: 00:21:63:28:b8:3b
> > > >                capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
> > > >                configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8187 driverversion=3.5.0-21-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.1.68 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bg

As I am new to ubuntu any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Thank you for providing some relevant details about your hardware. What is your issue exactly? Is your connection dropping out? Is this indicated or does it reports to be connected still? Or is it just slow? Please be specific.

Comment: @gertvdijk It tends to most commonly be dropping out but my main concern is the lack of range at a small distance compared to an OS such as Windows, which would maintain a perfect connection at these same ranges.

Comment: Thanks for the details. You appear to be running into a long-lived bug. see [LP #215802](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/215802) (now closed) and [LP #802902](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/802902) (seems like a follow up for new releases). Workarounds are posted, but your mileage may vary. If it's a cheap USB adapter you have there, please consider getting it replaced by a more supported one.

Comment: @gertvdijk Thanks for your help on the topic. Shouldn't worry me to much though as I still receive internet in my room (though sketchy at times). Hopefully a fix will be found eventually though.

Comment: Forgot to mention one thing: Please **edit** your question rather than posting new information in the comments. This helps keeping it a nice and clean Question and easier for others to read when they stumble upon it. Remember that this site is not a discussion forum. Thanks!

Comment: And those bars are a marketing trick... either you have or you do not have a connection ;)

Comment: @Rinzwind Both signal strength and signal quality measured by both endpoints are used in order to determine the link speed.